# Images wont show on website

Tags: html

OK so I am fairly new to html code and i have already created a website and have pictures on it but I cant get some to work

my html code for one for one the pages in in the same directory as the image but it just wont work. Here is the line of code#

```
<img src=test.jpg"" alt="test" width="1280" height="720">
```

i am using html5
and once again the image is in the same directory

Comment: What exactly is not working? The picture not showing up?

Answer (score 3):

```
<img src=test.jpg"" alt="test" width="1280" height="720">
```

This is wrong.
Replace it with:

```
 <img src="test.jpg" alt="test" width="1280" height="720">
```

Your quotation marks were placed wrong in src.

Answer (score 1):

**Replace**

```
<img src=test.jpg"" alt="test" width="1280" height="720">
```

**With following**

```
<img src="test.jpg" alt="test" width="1280px" height="720px">
```

Quotation marks to src were wrong...

Also check for case sesitivity...

E.g.
`test.jpg` is different from `Test.jpg`